# How to pass a newable `this` to a static method from a static method?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I pass a newable `this` to a static method from a static method?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgewCYFNkEBvAKAQQAcBXEZAS1gUmAkaWwDsA3fKCADwAVBPgAeEfJ1wYcBZAD4AFAFs8hAFwJO+AO4IlASgQBeBQiEAaBLlbAtwTgE8EAHwSOnAbQC6x4gC+pORUtAxMLGxMwMjIwqISUjJY6opGWgAKUNgq9GD4Ar7mZBQUyPiI9JIqYA7OvqYIviEUUBXUUJwp8gB0sFy8-EoQABZ51lX4NYYhQUGkKGgYAIIJktKyqSTz-Zxg2OU9yNgA5krLPTHIRtYXV0Z9XJBQ1PDYUD2cwCr4hkA)

```
abstract class Model {
  public static convert<T extends Model>(model: new () => T, data: any | any[]) { 
    return new model()
  }

  public static all<T extends Model>(): Promise<[]> {
    let items: any[] = []
    return Model.convert(this, items)
                      // ^--- Error is here
  }
}
```

The resulting JavaScript works, and I get an instance of `A`, however typescript complains with this error:

> Argument of type 'typeof Model' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Model'.

```js
class Model {
    static convert(model, data) { return new model() }
    static all() {
        let items = [];
        return Model.convert(this, items);
    }
}

class A extends Model { }

console.log(A.all(), A.all().constructor.name);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would normally work if `Model` were not `abstract`. If `Model` was not abstract `this` (which is typed as `typeof Model`) would have the `new () => Model` constructor, but since it is abstract, it does not have a callable constructor.

The simple solution is to add an annotation for `this` in the static method:

```
abstract class Model {
  public static convert<T extends Model>(model: new () => T, data: any | any[]): T[] { return null!; }

  public static all<T extends Model>(this: new () => T): Promise<T[]> {
    let items: any[] = []
    return Promise.resolve(Model.convert(this, items));
  }
}

class A extends Model { }


console.log(Model.all()) // err since Model does not have a ctor
console.log(A.all(), A.all().constructor.name)
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgewCYFNkEBvAKAQQAcBXEZAS1gUmAkaWwDsA3fKCADwAVBPgAeEfJ1wYcBZAD4AFAFs8hAFwJO+AO4IlASgQBeBQiEAaBLlbAtwTgE8EAHwSOnAbQC6hrUK+JAhQ+BDUUJza1MjIAIQA3AgAvqTkVLQMTCxsTMCxwqISUjJY6opKEAAW9GBaOvpGpuZC-ggAClDYKrX4wr7mZBQUyGEI9JIqdR7OQSYIvukUoeGRHV09YPgAdKFg2Mi8SnKE27BcvPyVNWDWE-hThoYJ6amppChoGACCRZLSsnKwXeHy4+1G22Q2AA5sdytt8sgjMYAPQo0RQKDMeicWD4MryGzYfAYTjYRBVYC8DxICDYKCgzjgnZQ2HfBGxIzWdmIoxnMHQajwenbTjAFT4QxAA)

This will make `all` un-callable for `Model` which is probably what you want anyway.

**Edit**

Since in your actual use case you want to call static methods from other static methods we need a slightly more complex annotation for `this`. The previous version just keeps the constructor signature and none of the static members. You need the static members represented by `typeof Model` in the annotation. The simplest way to do this is to add `typeof Model` in an intersection with the constructor signature we previously defined (`(new () => T)`) basically adding a constructor to the abstract class.

```
type NonAbstracModel<T extends Model> = (new () => T) & typeof Model
abstract class Model {
  public static convert<T extends Model>(model: NonAbstracModel<T>, data: any | any[]): T { return new model() }

  public static all<T extends Model>(this: NonAbstracModel<T>): T {
    let items: any[] = []
    return Model.convert(this, items)
  }

  public static find<T extends Model>(this: NonAbstracModel<T>, primaryKey: string | object) { }

  public static firstOrFail<T extends Model>(this:NonAbstracModel<T>) {
    this.find('abc')
  }

}

class A extends Model {}

console.log(A.all(), A.all().constructor.name)
```

Comment: Yeah, the last statement is true, I don't want `Model.all()`

Comment: I have this in another method, so I added it to the method params, `this: new() => T`, then places that call that method now get an error `this.find()`, it say for the this: `The 'this' context of type 'typeof Model' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'new () => T'.
  Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.`

Comment: [As you can see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgewCYFNkEBvAKAQQAcBXEZAS1gUmAkaWwDsA3fKCADwAVBPgAeEfJ1wYcBZAD4AFAFs8hAFwJO+AO4IlASgQBeBQiEAaBLlbAtwTgE8EAHwSOnAbQC6hrSLECFD4ENRQnNp6CGryRggAvqTkVLQMTCxsTMDIyMKiElIyWOqKShAAFvRgWjq68WYW-hYkKRTIoQj0kio1Hs6+pgi+bcGh4ZFyhAB0sFy8-OVVYNbd+L2GKUkpNHTsmewAZvTS+eKS0rKlypXVtdEN5lZUUPQqwFBOANL4TlqQr04AHM3AhsCAAFb4eDGMgUChTZCzeZ8CBLarWXybCjbCi7dLMCCsI70KCQADyUAAYsB6HkROcild5MpYaNbmBpsdpEoAOSgWC87GJZLbFBoDAAQQKF2KiJIYq4YGwHWmyGwQKUkumOWQRms2t1RmRnAB1Hg2Cg004wBU+EMQA)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn modified answer to address this use  case

Comment: Side note: `typeof Model` instead of `Model` basically means that it's not going to be an instance correct?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn sorry about not replacing all parameter types, fixed. The type denoted by the class name is the instance type. `typeof ClassName` represents the type of the class itself, (ie  it's an object type with the static members and the constructor that returns the instance type)